# Морфемный разбор слова "тетрадь"

Tags: морфология, морфемика

Как сделать морфемный разбор слова "тетрадь"? В словаре написано, что в слове нулевое окончание, но ведь корень - *тетрад* (тетради, тетрадью).

Так всё-таки нулевое окончание или мягкий знак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мягкий знак лишь обозначает мягкость предыдущего согласного тетра[д'], (тетра[д']и, а окончание нулевое

Comment: Спасибо! Появилось два вопроса - 1) корень слова "тетрадь" включает в себя мягкий знак? 2) может ли быть мягкий знак окончанием или это всегда лишь модификатор согласной?

Comment: Когда делают морфемный разбор,Ь включают в корень, ведь сам по себе в этом слове он не несёт ни грамматического, ни лексического значения, потому никогда не бывает самостоятельной морфемой. Иногда он несёт грамматическое значение: в глаголах после шипящих указывает на принадлежность к глаголу, а не на мягкость шипящих: мочь, пишешь, режь, в сущ. 3 склонения - на род сущ.:камыш-мышь.В этом слове обозначает мягкость согласного.Так что самостоятельным окончанием быть не может.

Comment: А в глаголе значит может?

Comment: Нет, окончанием быть не может.Пишешь-окончание -ешь, а буква Ь указывает на принадлежность к классу глаголов. Окончание- это значимая часть слова, а Ь сам по себе ничего в лексическом значении не значит, относится к графике.